# auto increment option

Tags: sql-server-2008, auto-increment

I need to set the auto increment option for a particular column in a row of a database to be true so that the value increments each time a new row is inserted.

How do i do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [IDENTITY property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) in TSQL

```
CREATE TABLE new_employees
(
 id_num int IDENTITY(1,1),
 fname varchar (20),
 minit char(1),
 lname varchar(30)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

The database column itself must be specified to be an identity...

- Using SQL Management Studio, open the table
- Expand the `Identity Specification` tree
- Alter the value of `Is Identity` to `Yes`
- `Identity Increment` will now be `1`, change it if necessary

Comment: when i try to modify the identity specification field, the is identity field doesnt give an option to be changed. !!that is, its in non-editable mode.
And what is a dbml file?? where is it located.? i am using visual studio to deelop an application which accesses this mssqlserver 2008

Comment: I removed the `dbml` reference - that was my stupidity, forgive me. What type of value does the field store? Auto-incrementation won't work with just any random type, it will have to have be of sequential nature.

Comment: ya. i want it to be of sequential type only.I want to add a column which will store sequential number so  that i can use it as primary key..

Comment: Next to `Identity Specification`  you should be a `+` sign, click it to expand the options, then proceed.